# javascript React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a problem, I consume a service that brings me a button array for a dynamic menu. This array I want to put in the screen, like button has an id for an action in specific.

Code

```
var sizes = []
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.tallas.length; i++) {
            sizes.push(
                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.clothingSizeItem, this.state.idSize === this.state.tallas[i].id ? styles.activeClothingSizeItem:null]}
                    onPress={() => this.fetchSizeData(this.state.tallas[i].id)}>
                    <Text style={this.state.idSize === this.state.tallas[i].id ? styles.activeSizeText:null}>
                        {this.state.tallas[i].name}
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        }

render() {
   return(
     <View>
       {sizes}
     </View>
  )
}
```

The problem is when I press a button from my dynamic menu, the button calls a function that receives a parameter, but this parameter comes from the service array. So I used the "i" param from for, but this variable ("i") can't be found after the screen was rendered.

Screen Shot
[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqFOP.png)

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of a for loop:

```
const sizes = this.state.tallas.map(item => (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.clothingSizeItem, this.state.idSize === item.id ? styles.activeClothingSizeItem:null]}
        onPress={() => this.fetchSizeData(item.id)}>
        <Text style={this.state.idSize === item.id ? styles.activeSizeText:null}>
            {item.name}
        </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

The reason the `for` loop doesn't work here is that the index variable `i` is incremented on every iteration of the loop, so by the time the callback ends up being called (long after the loop has completed), the value `i` is always it's final value (same as `tallas.length`).